# How to use beesu on fedora (the gksu alternative)?

Tags: fedora, gnome, password, root

I'm on fedora 25 gnome, I installed `beesu` and `beesu-nautilus-manager` as an alternative for `gksu`

When I try to open an application using `beesu` it asks me to enter root password, I do that, it says it's wrong, but it isn't.

Do I need save my password in `seahorse - password and keys` application in fedora in order for beesu to work? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Please note that fedora doesn't let you install gksu, so switching is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an ugly script to somewhat emulate `gksudo`

- tested on Fedora 31
- works with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

#### Usage

```
~$ wsudo [cmd]
```

(default is `gnome-terminal`)

#### code

Place the following code in `/usr/local/bin/wsudo`. You also need to install the `gtkdialog` package

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $GTKDIALOG ] && GTKDIALOG=gtkdialog

MAIN_DIALOG='
<window>
  <hbox>
    <entry>
      <variable>PASSWORD</variable>
      <visible>password</visible>
      <action signal="activate">exit:OK</action>
    </entry>
    <button ok></button>
  </hbox>
</window>
'
export MAIN_DIALOG

tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/wsudo-XXXXX.$$)

$GTKDIALOG -c --program=MAIN_DIALOG >"$tmpfile"

. "$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile"

#small script to enable root access to x-windows system 
xhost +SI:localuser:root
if [ -z "$1" ];then
        echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S gnome-terminal
else
        echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S "$@"
fi
#disable root access after application terminates
xhost -SI:localuser:root
#print access status to allow verification that root access was removed
xhost
```

Comment: Works well, but gtkdialog is not readily available on Fedora 35 :(

Comment: Since 34, I just use terminal profiles and keep a red root terminal always open lol

Answer (score 1):

this is a wayland problem. This is an intentional design decision of wayland, see Bug [1274451](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451)

All the credits go to a user on [Ask fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/102930/how-to-use-beesu-on-fedora-the-gksu-alternative/). I'm just answering my question to close this topic.